# snap: xdg-open does nohing

Tags: snap, xdg-open

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I installed only ubuntu-standard without GUI and then added `awesome` window manager without `gdm`. I use only `startx`.
Recently, I started using `spapd`. For instance, I have installed `firefox` and `thunderbird` via `snap`. In all snaps I have the problem that `xdg-open` is doing nothing. Hence, clicking on a link in an email in `thunderbird` does not open `firefox`. However, outside of snap apps, `xdg-open http://wikipedia.org` opens `firefox`. In contrast, `snap run --shell firefox` followed by the same `xdg-open` command does nothing. I observed that this problem does not exist on an Ubuntu 20.04 installation with GNOME desktop. According to web search, I think various people run into this issue, however the problem seems to remain open.

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.xinitrc` add the following command before `exec awesome`:
`eval "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session)"`

Further, install the following packages:
`apt install dbus-x11 xdg-dbus-proxy xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`.